# Android custom shape do not fits ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-drawable, shapes

I want to make white circle as background for ImageView.
I have a custom shape for that:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:innerRadius="0dp"
        android:thickness="35dp"
        android:useLevel="false"
        android:shape="ring">
        <solid
            android:color="@color/white"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

well, ok, if I specify

```
    "android:thickness="35dp"
```

in this shape it looks good in ImageView.
But if I change it to 75dp (for example) background of the ImageView is just **totally white, not white circle**.
I'm wondering, because ImageView usually scales images I put as background.
Is there a way to have the same behaviour relating to custom shape?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `roundedImageView` library https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView. I used it more than two years and i havent complain from it at all. Just add this line in your `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
}
```

and you can define custom image view widget like this

```
<com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:src="@drawable/photo1"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:riv_corner_radius="30dip"
        app:riv_border_width="2dip"
        app:riv_border_color="#333333"
        app:riv_mutate_background="true"
        app:riv_tile_mode="repeat"
        app:riv_oval="true" />
```

with this library you can define:

`app:riv_corner_radius=""`
`app:riv_border_width=""` 
 `app:riv_border_color=""`

Hope to help!

Comment: @Kristian, thanks, I can do that (and I use something like this sometimes). But now I want to make it excluding ext library, and faced this problem. Circle is only an example, later I will use another shapes and I definitely don't want to search libraries for each of that shapes ;)

Comment: @GoltsevEugene yea for you case you are right to don`t want to use ex library, how many shapes and what are they can you tell me ?

Comment: 8digit shape, infinity shape, heartshape, cogwheel ... many of them. Also, I have a feeling that this knowledge will help me much in future )